# Setting up a portable OS

Tags: linux, vmware-player

I'm running Ubuntu on VMware Player. Can i migrate the current virtual machine on a flash drive ? I want to be able to plug it and then open it with VMware Player and edit my files and save them. I don't want to reboot the computer and then open the OS. Also, if i use it on an infected computer, would it get affected ?

Long story short, i want to carry the OS on a flash drive, and then plug it on a  computer and use the available hardware, without the need of installing VMware player on the host computer, and without getting infected. Is this possible ?

Comment: If you currently have to reboot your system to launch your virtual machine, you are doign something strange, because you shouldn't have to do that.  As for moving the virtual machine, move the virtual HDD files to the flash device.  You should also move the virtual machine configuration file to the flash device.  Manually modify the configuration, so it attempts to locate the virtual HDD, on same location as the configuration file.  Your other questions are extremely broad, a Windows infection, isn't going to infect a Linux VM.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your reply. I meant to say that i don't want to need to reboot the computer to get access to the OS on the flash drive because i came across a tool that serves my purpose but it requires me to boot from the flash drive.

Comment: You were booting to the virtual machine, which is what you want, but you can place everything on the flash drive and install VM Player each time you want to use it if you want.  Just a lot more work.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, i need to edit my question to avoid this confusion.